# How to solve the Summation equation by FindRoots

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions, probability-or-statistics

I want to find out the value of alpha and lambda where u lies between 0 and 1.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide some Mathematica code, thanks. What's the difference between `t` and `t(i)`?

Comment: Let T1, T2, . . . , Tn be a random sample of any distribution with cdf F(·), and suppose that T(i), i =
1, 2, . . . , n denotes the ordered sample.

Comment: The two equations don't depend on `\ [Lambda] `.

Comment: they are depending on lambda as well as alpha if you observed you cans see both equations involve these parameters.

Comment: Look at definition of `t` : The summation only contains quotient `\ [Lambda]/t[[i]]` which by definition is a function of` `u,\[Alpha]` . That's my point!

Comment: we calculate the values of t and then solve it by arranging min to macx value

Comment: please help me to solve these equations

Comment: Again have a look on your definitions. From the definition of `t` it follows `\[Lamda/t==-Log[1-u^(1/\[Alfa] ]`. If you substitude this expression into the two sums the  parts `\[Lamda/t(i)` become `-Log[1-u(i)^(1/\[Alfa] ]` . No `\Lamda]` anymore in the two sums!

Comment: Sir we did not use its expression on it we use its values

Comment: we use some initial values on it and get the values of lambda and alpha

Comment: Please show your effort as Mathematica code. Show the way you calculate `t[i]`!

Comment: i did like this but not get coorectly

Comment: Please edit your question and show the mathematica code . You can show the code if you indent 4 spaces or include the code inside  `...`

Comment: As far as I see nothing changed, quotient `\[Lamda/t(i)` is  substituded -Log[1-u(i)^(1/\[Alfa] ]`.Try to understand my argumentation!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not  a copy past machine. It's your part to provide usable code!

Comment: Sorry sir i am not saying this

Comment: Please help me to solve out this problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not clearly stated, the code is not present, the code presented in Wolfram Community showed no indication of debugging effort, there were two variables but only one equation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, hopefully a step forward to clarify the question( see my comments) and to show, that the two sum's don't depend on `\[Lambda]`

```
n=5;
u = RandomReal[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], n] // Sort;
t = -λ/Log[1 - u^(1/α)] ;

λ/t
(*{-Log[1 - 0.110733^(1/α)], -Log[1 - 0.248464^(1/α)], -Log[1 - 0.527917^(1/α)], -Log[1 - 0.626329^(1/α)], -Log[1 - 0.790666^(1/α)]}*)
```

That is list `λ/t[[i]]`. As you might see it doesn't depend on `λ`!!!

**That's why the two sum's only depend on `α` and therefor can't be solved for `α,λ` !!!**